# Optimize Conditions

Tags: c++, if-statement

I've a simple question about conditions in `if` and `for` or `while` loops.
Is there any way that lets me verify this condition with less lines of code?

```
if (are_you_sure != "Si" && are_you_sure != "si" && are_you_sure != "No" && are_you_sure != "no")
```

I don't think I can minimize the code above, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: You could lowercase the string first and then only have two conditions to check. You could wrap the check into a function, something like `if (InvalidResponse(are_you_sure)) { ... }`. You could put the valid values in a container like an `unordered_set` and check if there's a match that way. Lots of things you can do, but if you only check it once in one place and the list of things you're going to check against isn't likely to change then what you have might be the best way to keep it close for someone reading the code.

Comment: There is an interesting answer in this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493523/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493523/487892)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit that adds a solution. Please add that as an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a lot less code, and make it more readable, if you have a function that does that for you:

```
if (none_of( are_you_sure, "Si", "si", "No", "no"))
  // ...
```

Of course, that function has to be written, but it's not too much code with c++17 fold-expressions:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Opts>
auto none_of(T val, Opts ...opts)
{
    return (... && (val != opts));
}
```

This has some nice properties; it can take any number of arguments, and also be used with types other than strings:

```
int n = 42;
if (none_of( n, 1, 2, 3))
  // ...
```

Make sure to name the function well, as that affects readability a lot.