# How to create a group of constants and check if a variable is or isn't included in that group?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I want to create an `if` code to check if variable `x` is a member of a defined group of constant named `a`, for example `a = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 }`, then use something like `if (x != a)`.

I only know to use it like this
`if ( ( x != 1 ) || ( x != 2 ) || ( x != 3 ) || ( x != 4 ) )`

Comment: Look into `std::set`.

Comment: What resource are you using to learn C++? Not insulting you - just trying to figure out how best to direct you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if given int exists in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299508/how-can-i-check-if-given-int-exists-in-array)

Comment: If `x` is an integer type, `(x != 1) || (x != 2)` is always true, You probably mean `(x == 1) || (x == 2)` or it complement `(x != 1) && (x != 2)`

Comment: Not the most efficient, but one-liner: `bool found = std::set{1, 2, 3, 4}.count(x);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimize Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447353/optimize-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions like this

```
bool exist_in_group(int value, const int* group,int group_size)
{
    bool res{false};
    for(int i=0;i<group_size;i++)
    {
        if(group[i] == value)
            res = true;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This function check if value exist in your array(group) or not

Comment: I'm aware of that method, but I wanted to ask if there are some default function available in C++ to save me some time to write out a new function myself.
Thank you anyway!

Comment: you can use `std::find`  instead

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. If the values are constant numbers you know at compile time, you could use a switch to check, then put that in an immediately imboked lambda to be able to call it as an expression:

```
if ( [](int x){
    switch(x){case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: return true;}
    return false;}(x) ) {
  std::cout << "x is contained in group\n";
}
```

Could also use a function instead of a lambda, if you use it in many places and the group of numbers is fixed.