# How to make a while loop but with more conditions C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
cout << "Options:\n1: Change Name\n2: Change Password\n3: Change Address\n4: Withraw\n5: Deposit\nL: Log out\n>";
while (user_input2 != '1' && user_input2 != '2' && user_input2 != '3' && user_input2 != '4' && user_input2 != '5' && user_input2 != 'L')
{
    cout << "Invalid input";
}
```

So how do I just shortened the while conditions?

I tried doing:

```
cout << "Options:\n1: Change Name\n2: Change Password\n3: Change Address\n4: Withraw\n5: Deposit\nL: Log out\n>";
while (user_input2 != '1','2','3','4','5','L')
{
    cout << "Invalid input";
}
```

but it doesn't work.

edit1: "I added more hints to what I wanted to do"

Comment: The comma operator may compile but it will not do what you want.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your first block code. By using "or" `||`, the condition will always be satisfied with any value `user_input` can take. I think you meant to use the "and" `&&` operator.

Comment: This seems like a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447353 though it uses `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: I just found an older duplicate but that one is better. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181579/c-most-efficient-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values)

Comment: @drescherjm That's perfect, thanks.

Comment: Are the values that you're comparing against always going to be chars? And will they be contiguous?

Comment: Yes they're chars

Comment: Ok, and will they be contiguous, i.e. do you care about cases like `user_input2 != '1','3','5', '8'`?

Comment: Actually I don't care if the numbers are in order or not, these chars are just options plus the L which will be the quitting option to the while loop, I'm just wondering which is a way where the "user_input2 !=" condition to be implemented to all the chars I want without typing too much. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `<` and `>` operators for the range of `'1'` to `'5'`, but you'll have to handle the check for `'L'` explicitly:

```cpp
while (user_input2 != 'L' && (user_input2 < '1' || user_input2 > '5'))
{
    cout << "Invalid input";
}
```

Comment: Maybe a short explanation about character encodings to help a beginner programmer?

Comment: @Patrick — character encodings aren’t really involved here. In C++ and C the digits `[‘0’ .. ‘9’]` are required to be contiguous and increasing. So that test is valid for every character encoding that the compiler supports.

Comment: it didn't work, the char inputs have an L in it. so the options are ('1','2','3','4','5','L')

Comment: @MJDelosSantos A little more effort. The condition proposed here takes care of cases where `user_input2` is a digit between 1 and 5. If you have an extra valid character you can use this: `input < '1' || input > '5' || input == 'L'`.

Answer (score 3):

You also can write:

```
while (user_input2 != '1' && user_input2 != '2' && user_input2 != '3' && user_input2 != 
'4' && user_input2 != '5')
{
    cout << "Invalid input"
}
```

Comment: This while conditions are just too long, I just want to shortened it to save my fingers and time typing it.

Answer (score 2):

How about a function where you provide all accepted characters as string?

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>

bool checkValid(char cChk, std::string_view allowed)
{
  for (char c : allowed) if (cChk == c) return true;
  return false;
}

int main()
{
  char user_input2;
  std::cin >> user_input2;
  if (!checkValid(user_input2, "12345L")) {
    std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
  }
}
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/620498e726ed146a)

Btw. there is a standard C library function (adopted in C++ standard) which could be used as well:

[**std::strchr()**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr)

It returns a pointer to found character or `nullptr` and could be used similar like `checkValid()` in the above sample:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char user_input2;
  std::cin >> user_input2;
  if (!std::strchr("12345L", user_input2)) {
    std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
  }
}
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1e7dbd65babb67d)

---

Thinking twice (about OPs possible intention), I started to ask why the check is needed at all. Assuming that the valid input has to be processed somehow (I would use a `switch` for this), invalid input just could be covered as well.

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  for (char user_input2; std::cin >> user_input2;) {
    switch (user_input2) {
      case '1': std::cout << "Change Name\n"; break;
      case '2': std::cout << "Change Password\n"; break;
      case '3': std::cout << "Change Address\n"; break;
      case '4': std::cout << "Withraw\n"; break;
      case '5': std::cout << "Deposit\n"; break;
      case 'l': case 'L': std::cout << "Log out\n"; return 0;
      default: std::cerr << "Invalid input!\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Input:

```
12AL
```

Output:

```
Change Name
Change Password
Invalid input!
Log out
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de7b1af48fb84d28)