# Return only specific characters within a string recursively C++

Tags: c++, string, recursion

I'm currently learning C++ but am having trouble wrapping my head around recursion. The problem at hand is to go through a string and only return the operators within it: i.e., '(' or '[' or '{' or ')' or '}' or ']'. Unfortunately, my program keeps returning the empty string. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <string>

string operatorsOnly(string s) {
  if (s.length() == 0) {
    return "";
  }
  if (s[0] != '(' or '[' or '{' or ')' or '}' or ']') {
    return operatorsOnly(s.substr(1, s.length() - 1));
  }
  else {
    return s[0] + operatorsOnly(s.substr(1, s.length() - 1));
  } 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ multiple strings inside an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484761/c-multiple-strings-inside-an-if-statement)

Comment: Also, although using `or` "works", you really should be using `||` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a variable against multiple values with that syntax. You need to do:

```
if (s[0] != '(' or s[0] != '[' or s[0] != '{' or s[0] != ')' or s[0] != '}' or s[0] != ']') {
  // ...
```